# java creating object suggestion

Tags: java

I have some doubts/questions regarding the object creation. I have heard that
objects should not be created in the loop. Whats wrong with the creation of 
objects inside the loop? Whats the difference between creating  outside the loop
and creating inside the loop?

Please consider the following example.

```
public java.util.List<Object> objectCreationTest(){
    java.util.List<Object> objectList =new java.util. ArrayList<Object>();
    Object obj = null;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <1000;i++){
        Object e = new Object(); //1 -->  Is this object creation wrong? 
        obj = new Object(); //2 --> Is this right way to create?
        objectList.add(e );

    }

    return objectList ;

}
```

Please suggest me which way I have to follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have heard that objects should not be created in the loop. Whats
>   wrong with the creation of objects inside the loop?

There's nothing wrong with creating objects in a loop. Sometimes it's the only way to create a number of (related) objects.

In your example, you can simply do:

```
public java.util.List<Object> objectCreationTest(){
    java.util.List<Object> objectList = new java.util. ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i <1000;i++){
        Object e = new Object(); 
        objectList.add(e);    
    }
    return objectList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches are right but the difference is scope of  `obj` and garbage collection .

```
public java.util.List<Object> objectCreationTest(){
java.util.List<Object> objectList =new java.util. ArrayList<Object>();
Object obj = null;
for(int i = 0 ; i <1000;i++){
    Object e = new Object(); //1 -->  Is this object creation wrong? 
    obj = new Object(); //2 --> Is this right way to create?
    objectList.add(e );

}

return objectList ;

}
```

In case 1 scope of `obj` is only inside  `for`  loop ,it will be  unreachable out side for loop once loop is finished it will be eligible for garbage collection  . In case 2 scope of `obj` is also out side of loop. In your case where you are just inserting objects in collection approach 1 is better because all objects will be eligible for garbage collection one by one after inserting in `objectList` if you use approach 2 then the `obj` has the reference to  last object which will be created when i=999 and the collector will check for the reference of `obj` after loop whether it is reachable or not means it scan whole .

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can simply do this:

```
public java.util.List<Object> objectCreationTest(){
    java.util.List<Object> objectList = new java.util. ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i <1000;i++){
        objectList.add(new Object());    
    }
    return objectList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only a difference in declaration, not in the actual creation. In theory there can be difference between the two, but it is so little, and the compiler probably takes are of it.

In your example, you can write this:

```
public java.util.List<Object> objectCreationTest(){
    java.util.List<Object> objectList =new java.util. ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i <1000;i++){
        objectList.add(new Object());    
    }
    return objectList;
}
```